# How to parse a possibly unknown dotnet type expression from string?

Tags: c#, parsing

I have a string that describes an arbitrary complex dotnet type, for example `System.Int32[]` or `` System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+KeyCollection `` or `` System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Int32,System.Int32] ``. I would like to parse it to some object that represents the inner structure of the type expression. The catch is, the contained types don't have to be in any way known to the runtime, so `Type.GetType(s)` is not the way to go here.

I am especially interested in generic types, and I refrain from writing the parser myself. Is there some utility offered by C# to deal with it?

Comment: Would these expressions be compilable by a C# compiler?

Comment: Fixed my question. I mean CLR types, for example those printed by `GetGenericTypeDefinition`

Comment: What are you trying to do? Explain the actual problem, not what you think the solution is. What you posted is just type names. There's no expression or inner structure. You can use those type names with `Type.GetType(string)` to get the actual type.

Comment: What are you trying to do and have you thought of the security implications? What you describe is dangerously close to what [BinaryFormatter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/binaryformatter-security-guide) does, which allows injecting and executing arbitrary code into an application through a serialized document - deserializing the document could end up creating types the application didn't expect. That's why it was deprecated and actively being removed from .NET Core

Comment: I am trying to write a wrapper over reflection that performs a customized lookup for types and assemblies. It happens that I receive a type descriptions that cannot be resolved within any of the assemblies in range, and I have to perform a custom search. For that I need to know what basic types I have to find to form a `TypeReference` from `Mono.Cecil`.

Comment: There is nothing (public) in the runtime that will parse a type name and expose some sort of parse tree for it, as opposed to just parsing it and looking up the type. Writing one is of course quite possible; the rules for type names are documented in ECMA-335.

Comment: That still sounds like [BinaryFormatter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/binaryformatter-security-guide) which `is insecure and can't be made secure.` precisely because it allows arbitrary type deserialization. What's the actual problem you want to solve? `I receive a type descriptions that cannot be resolved` then throw an exception and possibly block the sender that broke the contract.

Comment: If the types *aren't* arbitrary, [GetType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.gettype?view=net-6.0) has [overloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.gettype?view=net-6.0#system-type-gettype(system-string-system-func((system-reflection-assemblyname-system-reflection-assembly))-system-func((system-reflection-assembly-system-string-system-boolean-system-type))-system-boolean)) that allow custom assembly and type resolution. Have you tried these?